# Countdown timer not working smoothly

Tags: android

I am using countdown timer to count down time and it is not working smoothly to count down multiple times.

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(new Long(leftOverTime), 1000) {
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    tv_workout_time.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
    leftOverTime = millisUntilFinished;
  }

  public void onFinish() {
    newWorkoutMethod();
  }
}.start();
```

Comment: what do you mean "not working smoothly"?

Comment: I am using the countdown timer one after another. When the second one starts, it jumped number from 20 second to 18. And there is also a short pause in between the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Try my code, I think You need to break out the start timer functionallity and call it in `onFinish()` method.

```
 public void startTimer(int countersId){
 Counter counter = null;
 switch(countersId){
 case 0:
 counter = new CounterOne(countersId,your_input1,1000);
 break;  
 /* Counter 1 to 3  goes here*/
 default:
 break;
 }
 if(counter !=null ){
 counter.start();
 }
 }
```

And call your next timer in `onFinsh()` method.

```
 public abstract class Counter extends CountDownTimer
 {
 private int countersId;

 public Counter(int countersId /*counter id start with 0*/,long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
  {
 super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
 this.countersId = countersId;
 }
 public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);
 public void onFinish()
 {
  playMusic(song_1);
  runTask(your_input_1);
  startTimer(this.countersId++);
  }
  }

public class CounterOne extends Counter{
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
{
                //counter 1 logic
 }
}
```

Comment: I gave it a try and it gave me the same results. It works fine with the first timer but at the third timer it just jumped from 20 seconds to 18, leaving 19 behind. Is there a possibility that the timer can't handle me running it one after another?

Comment: Calling three timers in the same activity?

Comment: So from ur new solution is suggesting me to use two timer instead?

Comment: no, you can use multiple timers as you want...try it first